# How to toggle class in jQuery while applying css styling for :before and :focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm working on these buttons. When someone clicks the button it should mark it as pink and apply a checkbox before the work. If they click on the other button it should remove the class and apply the styling to the new. So here's where I'm stuck.

Here's the HTML:

```
<button button_type="one" class="btn wk-prd-btn wk-click" style="margin-right: 15px; border-radius: 1px;">
    ONE</button>
  <button button_type="two" class="btn wk-prd-btn wk-click " style="border-radius: 1px;">
    TWO</button>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.pink{
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial;
 font-size: 16px !important;
 background-color: inherit;
 border: solid 1px #0d1c25;
 width: 165px;
 font-weight: 200;
 padding-top: 1em !important;
 padding-right: 2.6em !important;
 padding-bottom: 1em !important;
 padding-left: 2.6em !important;
 box-shadow: none !important;
 content: "";
 font-family: "fontawesome";
}

.pink:focus:before{
 content: "";
 font-family: "fontawesome";
}
```

This right here will apply the styling AND the content to the button(s):

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
      $(this).addClass('pink');
      $('<style> .pink:focus:before{content: "",font-family: "fontawesome";}</style>').appendTo('.btn');
    });
```

Cool. Operates as it should. But the moment I want to toggle to the other button it strips out the styling with the content. I'm using the below to remove the class:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
      $('.btn').not(this).removeClass('pink');
      $(this).toggleClass('pink')
    })
```

As a relative noob to jQuery (thank you StackOverflow for the crash course) is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Can you make jsbin, codepen with your code so we can see it in action ?

Comment: @Zvezdas1989 It would be preferred that any additional code was posted here.

Comment: But we need all the code so we can help you. Make a snippet in that case.

Comment: Working on a Codepen. It doesn't really like the CSS. Updated with HTML and CSS code.

Comment: You should just put that `.pink:before` style rule in your real stylesheet.

Comment: I think @NiettheDarkAbsol solved it when you posted `CSS` that's why I told to post all the code

Comment: Tried that. It royally messes up the styling by doing that. Something I'm okay with fixing but once I add in the removeClass it won't reapply the styling to the other button.